# list.files pattern for specific word and file extension

Tags: r, list, csv, file

I'm trying to list all files that include a specific word ("students") and file extension (".csv") in their file name. I want to do this through pattern but I must be doing something wrong.

```
# (1) Create File List
pat=paste("students","*\\.csv$")
csv_files <- list.files (path       = "R/win-library/Practice/Schoolprac/", 
                         pattern    = pat, 
                         recursive  = T,
                         full.names = T)
```

The file should include the word "students" and be a .csv file. What could I be doing wrong? Students doesn't need to be right before .csv nor at the beginning, just included. I'm not getting an error, just no results.

Comment: did the proposed solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
   pattern = '.*students.*\\.csv$'
```

You can test regular expressions in R with this [tester](https://spannbaueradam.shinyapps.io/r_regex_tester/)

Comment: recall this will match `students123csv` which is not a file. You should escape the dot to make it literal. Also use `*` instead of `+` ie. using `+` will not match `students.csv`